Why did Miles say "Snitch" here?
While escaping from Miguel and trying to get home to save his father
from impending death, Miles hooks a web onto one of the cars speeding
on the vertical highway.

Miguel: You're an anomaly!
Miles: Not if you let me go home! Snitch!

Here is the scene where the text "Snitch!" appears near Miles:

It’s a slang term often used to refer to someone who tells on someone else.
But Miguel never betrayed Miles nor revealed his secrets
Why did Miles say "Snitch" here?

Miles evades Miguel and rolls under the car. For a moment Miguel can't see him and is in danger of losing him in the traffic until the lady in the car points out that Miles is swinging down the other side of the car. She's the snitch.

Snitch (verb): to inform on someone.
Dictionary of Contemporary Slang 3rd Ed.

It's probably easier to see if you slow it down.

